# ngSubmit not firing in child component that implements ControlValueAccessor when using [formGroup]

Tags: angular

I came across a case where ngSubmit doesn't fire inside a child component, but only when using [formGroup]. If I use formGroupName all works well, so I was wondering if someone could explain why the two are different?

Here are two scenarios that work, and the [formGroup] that does not. Any ideas what is happening, aren't the two approaches supposed to work the same?

```
<form [formGroup]="profileForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #clientForm="ngForm">
  <mat-form-field>
    First Name:
    <input matInput type="text" formControlName="firstName" />
    <mat-error *ngIf="profileForm.get('firstName').hasError('required')">Required</mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>

  <!-- working -->
  <div>[formControl] works</div>
  <app-address [formControl]="$any(profileForm.get('contact.address'))"></app-address>

  <!-- working -->
  <div>formGroupName works</div>
  <ng-container formGroupName="contact1">
    <app-address formControlName="address"></app-address>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- NOT working -->
  <div>[formGroup] does not work</div>
  <ng-container [formGroup]="$any(profileForm.get('contact2'))">
    <app-address formControlName="address"></app-address>
  </ng-container>
</form>

<button type="button" (click)="clientForm.ngSubmit.emit(false)">Submit</button>
```

address.component.ts

```
constructor(
    private readonly _changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef,
    private readonly _formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private readonly _parentFormGroup: FormGroupDirective
  ) {
    this._ngControl = inject(NgControl, { self: true, optional: true });
    this._ngControl.valueAccessor = this;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.formControl = this._ngControl.control as FormControl;
    this.formControl.setValidators([this.validate.bind(this)]);
    this.formControl.updateValueAndValidity();

    this._parentFormGroup.ngSubmit.subscribe((item) => {
      console.log('submitted');
      this.addressFormGroup.markAllAsTouched();
      this.addressFormGroup.updateValueAndValidity();
      this._changeDetectorRef.markForCheck();
    });
  }
```

Finally here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-qeopc2-8kadst).

Answer (score 0):

- When we use `[FormGroup]`, we can directly binding the entire entire
  form group to the form element.

example:

```
<form [formGroup]="myFormGroup" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
 
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

In this example `(ngSubmit)` event is triggered when the form is submitted.

- When we use `formGroupName`, we can  binding a subgroup of the form to a specific element within the form.

example:

```
<form [formGroup]="myFormGroup" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div formGroupName="nestedGroup">
 
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

In this example `(ngSubmit)` event is still on the outer form.it will be triggered when the form is submitted. If this is working, but [formGroup] is not.